# How to submit a form with multiple input names

Tags: php, arrays, submit

I have this form.

```
<form action="products_identifiers_update.php" method="post">
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="2634" />
    <td>beret
        <input type="hidden" name="sku[]" value="beret" />
    </td>
    <td>B07BZXKMB4
        <input type="hidden" name="asin[]" value="B07BZXKMB4" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="connectionId[]" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="parent2634" name="isParent[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label class="parent" for="parent2634" style="width: 72px" data-on-label="Parent" data-off-label="Child"></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fba2634" name="isFba[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label for="fba2634" data-on-label="Yes" data-off-label="No"></label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1553" />
    <td>beret_bezowy_rudy_lis
        <input type="hidden" name="sku[]" value="beret_bezowy_rudy_lis" />
    </td>
    <td>B0776FFSTV
        <input type="hidden" name="asin[]" value="B0776FFSTV" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="connectionId[]" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="parent1553" name="isParent[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label class="parent" for="parent1553" style="width: 72px" data-on-label="Parent" data-off-label="Child"></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fba1553" name="isFba[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label for="fba1553" data-on-label="Yes" data-off-label="No"></label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1554" />
    <td>beret_bialy_czekolada_jenot
        <input type="hidden" name="sku[]" value="beret_bialy_czekolada_jenot" />
    </td>
    <td>B0776HRFHH
        <input type="hidden" name="asin[]" value="B0776HRFHH" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="connectionId[]" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="parent1554" name="isParent[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label class="parent" for="parent1554" style="width: 72px" data-on-label="Parent" data-off-label="Child"></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fba1554" name="isFba[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label for="fba1554" data-on-label="Yes" data-off-label="No"></label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1555" />
    <td>beret_bordo_czarno_bialy_jenot
        <input type="hidden" name="sku[]" value="beret_bordo_czarno_bialy_jenot" />
    </td>
    <td>B0776J6785
        <input type="hidden" name="asin[]" value="B0776J6785" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="connectionId[]" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="parent1555" name="isParent[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label class="parent" for="parent1555" style="width: 72px" data-on-label="Parent" data-off-label="Child"></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fba1555" name="isFba[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label for="fba1555" data-on-label="Yes" data-off-label="No"></label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <input type="hidden" name="id[]" value="1556" />
    <td>beret_brazowy_braz_syberyjski
        <input type="hidden" name="sku[]" value="beret_brazowy_braz_syberyjski" />
    </td>
    <td>B0776JGFS9
        <input type="hidden" name="asin[]" value="B0776JGFS9" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="connectionId[]" value="" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="parent1556" name="isParent[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label class="parent" for="parent1556" style="width: 72px" data-on-label="Parent" data-off-label="Child"></label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="fba1556" name="isFba[]" switch="primary" value="1" />
        <label for="fba1556" data-on-label="Yes" data-off-label="No"></label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="save">Save</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

When I submit it, it gives me only once:

```
foreach($_POST as $war => $val){
  echo $war.' = '.$val.'<br>';
}

id = Array
sku = Array
asin = Array
connectionId = Array
isFba = Array
isParent = Array
```

I don't know what is wrong and why it gives me **id = Array** and not **id = 2634** for example. Also when I click submit it gives me only one result and not 5. I do not know if it's the fault that I've been sitting in front of the computer for so long or how. Any ideas how to get:

```
    id = 2634
    sku = beret
    asin = B07BZXKMB4
    connectionId = 2222
    isFba = 1
    isParent = 

    id = 1553
    sku = beret_bezowy_rudy_lis
    asin = B0776FFSTV
    connectionId = 1111
    isFba = 
    isParent = 1
......
```

Comment: Because they are arrays. Execute a `print_r($_POST);` at the top of your script and you'll see everything.

Comment: `name="id[]"` If you use `[]` after that name, that tells the browser `id` is an array and it will pass that fields into the POST array as an array

Comment: When I remove [] and submit it, it gives me only the last result.

Comment: _“why it gives me id = Array”_ - **because** the value _is_ an array, any when you try to output an array with echo, the _text_ “Array” is all you will get. You should either loop over this sub-array to access its individual elements, or if you need this for debug purposes only, look into functions such as var_dump or print_r, that _can_ generate a proper text representation from arrays.

Answer (score 0):

In this case $_POST is an array of arrays, because you use `name="id[]"` on your `input` fields in the form, where the `[]` makes all these occurances arrays as well.

So processing them can be dont like this

```
foreach($_POST['id'] as $idx => $val){
    echo "id[$idx] = "      . $val;
    echo "sku[$idx] = "     . $_POST['sku'][$idx];
    echo "asin[$idx] = "    . $_POST['asin'][$idx];

    // etc etc
}
```